# I keep getting error message 1064 during execution

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE CLASS(
 student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 student_name VARCHAR(40),
 MAJOR VARCHAR(40),
 PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
);
```

I get the following error message

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE CLASS( student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
> student_name VARCHAR(40), MAJO' at line 2**

Some info. on what i am working with
Server Type: MySQL
Server Version: 8.0.20.0- MySQL Community Server

Comment: Hi, which column do you think is the primary key here ? your syntax is wrong.

Comment: You have defined the PK twice, but the error message actually implies that there was another query just before this one.

Comment: Since the error starts at the beginning of your query, you probably did something wrong right before that. Do you try to execute multiple queries at once?

Answer (score 1):

You should not define primary key twice in a table, this should work.

```
   CREATE TABLE CLASS(
     student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
     student_name VARCHAR(40),
     MAJOR VARCHAR(40)
    );
```

Comment: True, but that would actually generate a different error message

Comment: @Strawberry i can reproduce the error with this syntax CREATE TABLE CLASS( student_id INT PRIMARY KEY, student_name VARCHAR(40), MAJOR VARCHAR(40), 
..PRIMARY KEY(student_id) );

Comment: @samdarr even after copy pasting the above code i have presented , you are getting error ?

Comment: @Jfrd Again, that would be a different error message :-(

Comment: @Strawberry i totally see what you are saying, i got it, apology.

Comment: yes i try this many times but everytime it generates error

Comment: @samdarr as many people here pointed out mostly you have another query on top of create statement may be without the semicolon termination add ';' before create to separate and run also please try or post whole sql script you are trying to run so you can get max help.